# How to add additional subplots to a candlestick plot with a Bollinger Band?

Tags: plotly

https://www.kaggle.com/tencars/interactive-bollinger-bands-for-technical-analysis

The above example plots a candlestick plot with a Bollinger Band. I want to add separate panels for volume and MACD. How can I do it?

https://plotly.com/python/subplots/

Here shows an example on how to add stacked subplots. But I am not sure how to adapt it o the above Bollinger Band example. In the BB example, there are two subfigures, the top is the candlestick plot, the bottom is the sliding bar. However, the following doesn't have such things. How can I combine the two?

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[3, 4, 5],
    y=[1000, 1100, 1200],
), row=1, col=1)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[2, 3, 4],
    y=[100, 110, 120],
), row=2, col=1)

fig.append_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2],
    y=[10, 11, 12]
), row=3, col=1)


fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, title_text="Stacked Subplots")
fig.show()
```

The graph looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add `rangeslider=dict(visible=True)` into your `fig.update_layout()`, to be able to add the slider at the bottom. It is not a subplot, rather, it is a slider, so you do not need to use subplots.

Comment: How to remove the slider comes with Candlestick class?

Comment: Could you add a picture of what you are referring to? @user1424739